# expected begin_array but was begin_object retrofit 2. Trying to parse firebase database data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, gson, retrofit2

First of all thank´s for you to take some time to read this.
What i´m trying to do is parse my data from my firebase database with retrofit2.
Here goes my code.

```
public interface VenueApi {
@GET("users/Venue/{userUID}/.json")
Observable<List<Venue>> getData(@Path("userUID") String userUID);}

private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    String currentUserID;
    currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        // enable logging for debug builds
        HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        httpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);
    }


    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(String.valueOf(databaseReference))
            .callFactory(httpClientBuilder.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();

    VenueApi service = retrofit.create(VenueApi.class);

    Observable<List<Venue>> call = service.getData(currentUserID);


        call.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Venue>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Completed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Venue> listOfVenues) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            listOfVenues.get(0).getName(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            });
```

firebase database Venue

```
    @Parcel(Parcel.Serialization.BEAN)
public class Venue {
@SerializedName("rating")
private double mRating;
@SerializedName("id")
private String mId;
@SerializedName("stats")
private Stats mStats;
@SerializedName("url")
private String mUrl;
@SerializedName("price")
private Price mPrice;
@SerializedName("location")
private Location mLocation;
@SerializedName("photos")
private Photos mPhotos;
@SerializedName("name")
private String mName;
@SerializedName("categories")
private List<Category> mCategories;

public String getPushId() {
    return pushId;
}

public void setPushId(String pushId) {
    this.pushId = pushId;
}

private String pushId;
public Venue(){

}

public double getRating() {
    return this.mRating;
}

public void setRating(double rating) {
    this.mRating = rating;
}

public String getId() {
    return this.mId;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.mId = id;
}

public Stats getStats() {
    return this.mStats;
}

public void setStats(Stats stats) {
    this.mStats = stats;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return this.mUrl;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.mUrl = url;
}

public Price getPrice() {
    return this.mPrice;
}

public void setPrice(Price price) {
    this.mPrice = price;
}

public Location getLocation() {
    return this.mLocation;
}

public void setLocation(Location location) {
    this.mLocation = location;
}

public Photos getPhotos() {
    return this.mPhotos;
}

public void setPhotos(Photos photos) {
    this.mPhotos = photos;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.mName;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.mName = name;
}


public List<Category> getCategories() {
    return mCategories;
}

public void setCategories(List<Category> categories) {
    mCategories = categories;
}
```

}

And here is my firebase Database node.
[FirebaseDatabase Node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHBu2.jpg)
This is my logcat:

> 03-22 19:29:55.010 3611-3611/com.tripplanapp D/PostsFragment: Recycler view scroll position: 3
>   03-22 19:29:55.010 3611-3611/com.tripplanapp D/PostsFragment: Recycler view scroll position: -1
>   03-22 19:29:55.107 3611-4367/com.tripplanapp D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK https://tripplanapp-dc9ad.firebaseio.com/users/Venue/X4lpyZTnm1fi2a2tBtXAOUWkHVk2/.json (698ms)
>   03-22 19:29:55.108 3611-4367/com.tripplanapp D/OkHttp: Server: nginx
>   03-22 19:29:55.108 3611-4367/com.tripplanapp D/OkHttp: Date: Wed, 22 Mar 2017 22:29:56 GMT
>   03-22 19:29:55.108 3611-4367/com.tripplanapp D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>   03-22 19:29:55.108 3611-4367/com.tripplanapp D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 2792
>   03-22 19:29:55.108 3611-4367/com.tripplanapp D/OkHttp: Connection: keep-alive
>   03-22 19:29:55.108 3611-4367/com.tripplanapp D/OkHttp: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>   03-22 19:29:55.108 3611-4367/com.tripplanapp D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: no-cache
>   03-22 19:29:55.108 3611-4367/com.tripplanapp D/OkHttp: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload
>   03-22 19:29:55.108 3611-4367/com.tripplanapp D/OkHttp: {"-Kfcg9rdM3BbOamdJyOI":{"categories":[{"icon":{"height":0,"prefix":"","suffix":".png","width":0},"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d114951735","name":"Bookstore","primary":true}],"id":"4b0b3c73f964a520352f23e3","location":{"address":"Av. Paulista, 2073","cc":"BR","city":"São Paulo","country":"Brasil","formattedAddress":["Av. Paulista, 2073 (R. Augusta)","São Paulo, SP","01311-940","Brasil"],"lat":-23.559243786493667,"lng":-46.66020150999045,"postalCode":"01311-940","state":"SP"},"name":"Livraria Cultura","photos":{"count":1,"groups":[{"items":[{"height":612,"prefix":"","suffix":"/2748369_slBIrGav8OQ1NPcxXzW9knw540ElxeBGbSAZbGx2sAQ.jpg","width":612}],"name":"Venue photos"}]},"price":{"currency":"$","message":"Expensive","tier":3},"rating":9.7,"stats":{"checkinsCount":127470,"tipCount":1193,"usersCount":49189},"url":""},"-Kfd3stppxrp4W4cv6mc":{"categories":[{"icon":{"height":0,"prefix":"","suffix":".png","width":0},"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d114951735","name":"Bookstore","primary":true}],"id":"4b0b3c73f964a520352f23e3","location":{"address":"Av. Paulista, 2073","cc":"BR","city":"São Paulo","country":"Brasil","formattedAddress":["Av. Paulista, 2073 (R. Augusta)","São Paulo, SP","01311-940","Brasil"],"lat":-23.559243786493667,"lng":-46.66020150999045,"postalCode":"01311-940","state":"SP"},"name":"Livraria Cultura","photos":{"count":1,"groups":[{"items":[{"height":612,"prefix":"","suffix":"/2748369_slBIrGav8OQ1NPcxXzW9knw540ElxeBGbSAZbGx2sAQ.jpg","width":612}],"name":"Venue photos"}]},"price":{"currency":"$","message":"Expensive","tier":3},"rating":9.7,"stats":{"checkinsCount":127470,"tipCount":1193,"usersCount":49189},"url":""},"-Kfd3tTS_RKNzm1CZPAI":{"categories":[{"icon":{"height":0,"prefix":"","suffix":".png","width":0},"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d163941735","name":"Park","primary":true}],"id":"4b0588c7f964a520d9d922e3","location":{"address":"Av. Pedro Álvares Cabral, s/n","cc":"BR","city":"São Paulo","country":"Brasil","formattedAddress":["Av. Pedro Álvares Cabral, s/n (Av. Rep. do Líbano)","São Paulo, SP","04094-000","Brasil"],"lat":-23.58729483966111,"lng":-46.65717971681522,"postalCode":"04094-000","state":"SP"},"name":"Parque Ibirapuera","photos":{"count":1,"groups":[{"items":[{"height":612,"prefix":"","suffix":"/7155722_aTJwTX6aJRxWpp4wDGSjov9no6FkmCwV8eW-FLBlMy8.jpg","width":612}],"name":"Venue photos"}]},"rating":9.7,"stats":{"checkinsCount":352785,"tipCount":2294,"usersCount":94780},"url":""}}
>   03-22 19:29:55.108 3611-4367/com.tripplanapp D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (2792-byte body)

Comment: What is the value of `databaseReference`?

Comment: Is a Venue object, i editted my answer.

Comment: I mean somewhere in your code that mention `databaseReference = ...` because we need that to know on which part your retrofit is pointing at

Comment: Done! i´m really sorry, and thank´s for your time and patience.

Comment: No problem. Try replacing it to `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/Venue")` or `"users/venue/thatRandomIdOrSomething"` because in your current code, `databaseReference` is pointing at your database root. I'm not really understand your database concept so I'm not sure which data you want it to point at, but you now understand the concept, try changing String inside `getReference()` and see if that's what you want

Comment: I want to get a List<Venue> by the book the firebase database make us insert data using push() method so this generates a node based on timestamp, i guess this is why i can´t retrieve the data. the path of my firebase database venue is "users/Venue/(currentUserUID)/(pushmethodkey)"

Comment: Then try `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/Venue")`, honestly I don't have much experience when using Firebase Database combined with retrofit, so I won't be much help. Hope others can help you

Comment: I did try and the result was the same. Thank´s anyway!

Comment: From the image you've posted it doesn't look like a user has a list of venues, but a single venue object containing a map from id to venues. Did you try ``Observable<Venue> call = service.getData(currentUserID);``? I'm asking because this is what the error is telling you. It was expecting a list from your call but it got a single object.

Comment: Hi thank's for you time... Yes today i tryied this... in my logcat the venue appeared but when i call onNext on observable dont the toast print nothing on screen. @Override
                public void onNext(Venue listOfVenues) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            listOfVenues.getName(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }